# Laravel's built-in Auth functionality causes error when using localisation with prefixed urls

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I know the problem and already got a not satisfying solution... now I could need some help.

**Situation**:

- I am using Laravel's built-in Auth components.
- The project needs to
  be multilingual with a language switcher in the header.
- I created a middleware to handle this and also added the prefix attribute in the
  routes/web.php.
- Everything works fine with **simple urls**.

**./routes/web.php:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function() {
    // SOME URLS
    Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
}
```

**Language Switcher in header.blade.php:**

```
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}">ENG</a>
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'ru') }}">RUS</a>
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'de') }}">GER</a>
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'es') }}">ESP</a>
```

I looked at the password reset functionally that comes with Laravel that generates an url like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/password/reset/f88b70d78b984f96e0c567dfba9ab601f3c9deb39c9ab36e951310787411daf5?email=johndoe%test.com
```

**Problem**: Opening this url causes this error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: password.reset] [URI: {lang}/password/reset/{token}]. 
(View: D:\workspace\project\resources\views\components\header.blade.php)
```

The reason is clear: the language switcher urls are missing the `{token}` property.

**My solution:** To solve the problem I acutally pass the `email` and the `token` to my header.blade.php component and changed the langauge switcher to:

```
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'en', 'token' => $token ?? '', 'email' => $email ?? '']) }}">ENG</a>
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'ru', 'token' => $token ?? '', 'email' => $email ?? '']) }}">RUS</a>
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'de', 'token' => $token ?? '', 'email' => $email ?? '']) }}">GER</a>
<a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['lang' => 'es', 'token' => $token ?? '', 'email' => $email ?? '']) }}">ESP</a>
```

So in my opinion this solution is not maintainable. Just imagine I need to generate 10 urls and each with 10 different parameters. This would end in a chaos. I did not find any similar problem and also in Laravel's docs I could not find anything to handle such a situation. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: can't you do `App::getLocale()` or something like that instead of the `{lang}` parameter?

Comment: I guess you mean in the web.php where all routes declared? No, because then there would be always just 1 language in the url (base language from config/app). The language switcher would just use the ```['en','ru'...]``` as the ```{token}``` parameter like: ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/.../.../ru```

Comment: thats what I meant. on the language switcher you can set the locale and the route prefix will change

Comment: No. If the route group is changed in ```['prefix' => app()->getLocale()]``` the url always starts with a prefix from the config/app.php. In this case it will always be ```http://127.0.0.1:8000/en```. Without a defined prefix placeholder the language switcher tries to add the values (en, ru, de...) as a GET parameter and not as a prefix.